# iPhone 5 not charged enough to boot after 2 hours plugged in

Tags: iphone, battery, charging

Today I drained my iPhone 5's battery (went down to around 10%) and then went out in the cold (it is winter now and very cold, around 0ºC/32ºF). The phone died, and now I've left it on the charger for the last 2 hours, and the phone still hasn't turned on. Should I be worried? How long should I wait?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iPhone turned on the Apple logo and is now fully back on after almost 3 hours of charging. Turns out it may take 3 hours if battery is drained completely for iPhone 5 to turn back on.